# Refreshing an Activity's data while it's already displayed

Tags: android, android-activity

My company makes manufacturing equipment.  The equipment is controlled from a PC and the PC communicates with Android devices running our app (think: smartphones) over WiFi on the factory floor.

Most of the industrial processes are associated with Activity classes and their screens.  The factory worker selects one on the "phone", Android sends a message to the PC requesting that, and the PC sends a command and parameters which are used to launch that Activity and populate it with the parameters using intent *putExtra*'s.  The screens don't need to change or be updated again from the PC until they're closed.

But now I need an Activity which can be dynamically updated from the PC **while** it's being displayed.     I already have a thread in my app that receives commands from the PC continuously. But how do I update my Activity from that thread when an update from the PC arrives?   Should I register for some kind of broadcast, and if so what's the event my Activity should listen for?   Can I pass parameters via that, or do I need to put the parameters in some globally-accessible place?

Comment: why not do a job scheduler? it can fetch the information every 15 minutes (this is the minimum) and just setText to the textviews/listview or whatever view you got.

Comment: Do you mean "maximum"?  (I would need to update the display every 1 or 2 seconds).   Anyway where would it fetch the information from?  Would the JobScheduler run from the Activity?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `BroadcastReceiver` which you should register in `onStart()` and unregister in `onStop()` of your `Activity`.

This way the `Activity` will know there is an incoming update. If the size of the incoming data is small ("[a few KB](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles.html#sdba)" so you won't risk a `TransactionTooLargeException` on Android 7.0+) and if it's consisting of primitive data types or if it's some type of  `Parcelable` or `Serializable` then you can pass everything as `Intent` extra via the `BroadcastReceiver` to the `Activity`.

Another possibility would be to save the incoming data (e.g. to a internal storage or the SQLite database) and just notify the `Activity` via the `BroadcastReceiver`. Then the `Activity` can fetch the updates.

Comment: This looks promising.  The data will be integers or very short strings.  I didn't realise I could use intent extras with a broadcast receiver -  that makes it a lot easier.    I'll try this out and mark this as the answer if I can get it to work.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> I already have a thread in my app that receives commands from the PC
>   continuously

Since you want to change the `Activity`'s contents from a seperate `Thread` you need to actually change the contents of that `Activity` on the UI-Thread. You can define some static method in your `Application` which might be useful in this case:

```
public class ApplicationLoader extends Application {

    public static volatile Handler applicationHandler;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            applicationHandler = new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());
        }

        public static void runOnUIThread(Runnable runnable) {
            applicationHandler.post(runnable);
        }
}
```

With the `runOnUIThread()` you can call some method inside your `Activity` to update the contents. Call this in your `Thread`:

```
ApplicationLoader.runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        activity.updateMyActivity();
    }
});
```

If you can access your `Activity`'s instance, you can also use the inbuilt `runOnUiThread()`. The above solution is for `static` instances, but not recommended.

**Edit**

I also have some nice Observer code from Telegram for you:

```
public class NotificationCenter {

    private static int totalEvents = 1;

    public static final int updateActivity = totalEvents++;

    private final SparseArray<ArrayList<Object>> observers = new SparseArray<>();
    private final SparseArray<ArrayList<Object>> removeAfterBroadcast = new SparseArray<>();
    private final SparseArray<ArrayList<Object>> addAfterBroadcast = new SparseArray<>();

    private int broadcasting = 0;

    public interface NotificationCenterDelegate {
        void didReceivedNotification(int id, Object... args);
    }

    private static volatile NotificationCenter Instance = null;

    public static NotificationCenter getInstance() {
        NotificationCenter localInstance = Instance;
        if (localInstance == null) {
            synchronized (NotificationCenter.class) {
                localInstance = Instance;
                if (localInstance == null) {
                    Instance = localInstance = new NotificationCenter();
                }
            }
        }
        return localInstance;
    }

    public void postNotificationName(final int id, final Object... args) {
        if (Thread.currentThread() == ApplicationLoader.applicationHandler.getLooper().getThread()) {
            postNotificationNameInternal(id, args);
        } else {
            ApplicationLoader.runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    postNotificationNameInternal(id, args);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void postNotificationNameInternal(int id, Object... args) {
        broadcasting++;
        ArrayList<Object> objects = observers.get(id);
        if (objects != null && !objects.isEmpty()) {
            for (int a = 0; a < objects.size(); a++) {
                Object obj = objects.get(a);
                ((NotificationCenterDelegate) obj).didReceivedNotification(id, args);
            }
        }
        broadcasting--;
        if (broadcasting == 0) {
            if (removeAfterBroadcast.size() != 0) {
                for (int a = 0; a < removeAfterBroadcast.size(); a++) {
                    int key = removeAfterBroadcast.keyAt(a);
                    ArrayList<Object> arrayList = removeAfterBroadcast.get(key);
                    for (int b = 0; b < arrayList.size(); b++) {
                        removeObserver(arrayList.get(b), key);
                    }
                }
                removeAfterBroadcast.clear();
            }
            if (addAfterBroadcast.size() != 0) {
                for (int a = 0; a < addAfterBroadcast.size(); a++) {
                    int key = addAfterBroadcast.keyAt(a);
                    ArrayList<Object> arrayList = addAfterBroadcast.get(key);
                    for (int b = 0; b < arrayList.size(); b++) {
                        addObserver(arrayList.get(b), key);
                    }
                }
                addAfterBroadcast.clear();
            }
        }
    }

    public void addObserver(Object observer, int id) {
        if (broadcasting != 0) {
            ArrayList<Object> arrayList = addAfterBroadcast.get(id);
            if (arrayList == null) {
                arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                addAfterBroadcast.put(id, arrayList);
            }
            arrayList.add(observer);
            return;
        }
        ArrayList<Object> objects = observers.get(id);
        if (objects == null) {
            observers.put(id, (objects = new ArrayList<>()));
        }
        if (objects.contains(observer)) {
            return;
        }
        objects.add(observer);
    }

    public void removeObserver(Object observer, int id) {
        if (broadcasting != 0) {
            ArrayList<Object> arrayList = removeAfterBroadcast.get(id);
            if (arrayList == null) {
                arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                removeAfterBroadcast.put(id, arrayList);
            }
            arrayList.add(observer);
            return;
        }
        ArrayList<Object> objects = observers.get(id);
        if (objects != null) {
            objects.remove(observer);
        }
    }
}
```

Then make your `Activity` look like this:

```
public class ScheduleActivity implements NotificationCenter.NotificationCenterDelegate {

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        NotificationCenter.getInstance().removeObserver(this, NotificationCenter.updateActivity);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        NotificationCenter.getInstance().addObserver(this, NotificationCenter.updateActivity);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void didReceivedNotification(int id, Object... args) {
        if (id == NotificationCenter.updateActivity) {
            // update code, you can also define data in args
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `Thread`:

```
NotificationCenter.getInstance().postNotificationName(NotificationCenter.updateActivity, optionalData);
```

Comment: For  _activity.updateMyActivity();_ how do I get the instance of my Activity?  (startActivity() doesn't return an instance)

Comment: You can pass the instance of the activity to your thread object, since the thread only needs to run if you have started the Activity.

Comment: Also check my new code, this is a much more easy and flexible way.